# Unable to resolve clipboard using zClip - jQuery ZeroClipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this for copying text into clipboard..  (NOT GETTING MESSAGE AS '**text Copied in Cliboard**'

```
http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/
```

I have tried like this, but I am unable to get the copied text into clipboard..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.zclip.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('textarea#showthis').zclip({
        path: 'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy: function() {
            return $('#showthis').val();
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <textarea id="showthis" readonly>hi, how are you?</textarea>
 </body>
</html>
```

Please tell me what went wrong! (I am not aware of JavaScript and jQuery stuff!)

and I am using Chrome and I remembered correctly Flash already installed on my PC...

**EDITED:** What I am trying for: The text inside textarea should get copied as soon as I click 'TextArea'

Comment: I think clipboard functions are no more supported :(

Comment: Still NO.. May I know your code working for you..?

Answer (score 1):

You need a copy button. Zclip should be attached to the button which the user clicks to copy the text - not the textarea itself.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showthisButton").zclip({
        path: "js/ZeroClipboard.swf",
        copy: function () {
            return $('#showthis').val();
        }
    });
});
```

And the HTML should be this:

```
<textarea id="showthis">hi, how are you?</textarea>
<input type="button" id="showthisButton" value="Copy">
```

If you need any more help, just ask.

Comment: No bro, its not working for me.. I mean iam not getting any message as 'copied to clipboard'.. May i know, is that working for you..?

Comment: Hey I found another one from here: http://beckelman.net/2009/01/22/copy-to-clipboard-with-zeroclipboard-flash-10-and-jquery/

BUT surprisingly, its demo working in my browser, but when after I downloaded and checked, its not working.. Do you have any idea? Pls judt check this once.. all u need is to download and check it yourself (nothing to change the code in it..)

Comment: It's the same plugin - and it's better to download from the original website. Did the modified code not work?

Comment: it (beckleman code) worked for me when I checked into some site... not working locally.. i donno the reasons for it!

Comment: your code not working, even I tried uploading into some site..anyway, i found solution from beckleman site bro..  BTW, this is my another new query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13635252/need-custom-fields-on-products-page-and-should-get-fields-values-to-mail-as-well

can u pls look into? (and iam vm thank for you.. :) )